# Duda sobre redireccionamiento de viejo dominio al nuevo

Tags: reactjs, aws

cambie mi pagina de dominio y funciona bien, esta alojada en AWS  cloudfront. Puse a redireccionar el `viejoDominio.com` hacia `nuevoDominio.com` y este se redirecciona pero el problema llega cuando las personas tienen guardado en cache el `viejoDominio.com`, ya que este NO hace el redireccionamiento al nuevoDominio.com. Si el usuario se mete desde incognito no hay problema, al meterte al dominio viejo lo redirecciona al nuevo.

Por lo que el usuario puede navegar en la pagina como si esta estuviera disponible `viejoDominio.com/courses  .../users` y cualquier `pathname` que tenia esa url.

---

Existe alguna forma para solucionar eso?, para cuándo el usuario tenga cache en el navegador este mande al `nuevoDominio.com`

---

Comment: Usar una estrategia como ETag o similar para que el navegador vea que los recursos han cambiado y los vuelva a cargar. Eso sobre el caché de recursos. ¿Seguro que esa es tu pregunta? Sobre las redirecciones, el sitio debería redirigir cualquier petición de viejoDominio a nuevoDominio, a menos que la redirección sólo esté en el home. Faltan detalles de la redirección para saber qué puede fallar...

Comment: hola @Alfabravo gracias por la pronta respuesta, el redireccionamiento se esta haciendo con una configuración del gestor de dominio domain.com  el cual tiene una configuración de domain pointer y se coloco con los siguientes valores:

Pointer Type : URL Standard
Directory: newDomain.com


Con esa configuración No redirecciona solo a home, debe redireccionar a todas supongo

No estoy seguro si la pagina tiene Etag configurado, de no ser así la pagina cacheada que tiene los navegadores nunca se actualizara?

Comment: Es que el caché de recursos no impide que el navegador cargue lo que debe. Una cosa es cómo el navegador hace el DNS request de viejodominio, que da una IP y luego, cuando carga ese recurso, debería dar un 302 a nuevoDominio. Si la redirección está hecha en el gestor del dominio, entonces está mal hecha, porque el navegador va a preguntar por viejoDominio y el DNS del gestor de dominio le responderá "vaya a nuevoDominio". El caché DNS de los clientes puede demorar esto pero, como mucho, será un día (salvo configuraciones peculiares)